# Sitecore Rich Text Editor Links

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have this weird problem in Sitecore 7.0 where within the Rich Text Editor the internal links look like below

```
<a href="http://xys.com/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich%20Text%20Editor/~/link.aspx?_id=594621DB37464C17B6EFB0C6B8399415&amp;_z=z">
```

where the correct href should be

```
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=594621DB37464C17B6EFB0C6B8399415&amp;_z=z">
```

My editors don't know if they did something special for the link to be messed up like that, it is not across all the links. It does make me think that it is human error but I can't think how they could end up with such a URL?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the HTML Editor Profile that you are using (core database) `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles` and make sure that the Insert Sitecore Link is the same as the default one? You should have "InsertSitecoreLink" on the Click field